# On iOS, how come iPhone's Launch Image should include status bar, but iPad's Launch Image should not?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

The Apple Human Interface Guide (HIG) explicitly states that for iPhone Launch images, include the status bar, but for iPad, don't include it.  (please see the image at the end of question).  (The document revision is as of 2012/3/07).

So I supposed any status bar info (carrier, time, battery) will be automatically cropped by either Xcode or iPhone itself, so that it is not shown to the user.

But why the inconsistency for iPad?   For one, Xcode actually could take in an image, and if it sees that it is the full size 1024 x 768, then crop out the status bar region.  And are there other reasons?  Such as when iPhone or iPad launches an app, the status bar is always shown on one device while the other device won't always show it, and causing the difference in the rule?

---

Quoted: (displayed as an image)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

On iPhone/iPod, applications can overlap the status bar. iPad is assumed to have big enough screen for applications not to need to overlap the status bar.

Comment: by "overlap" I think you mean "cover up"...  but so is it true that for iPhone and iPad, they both can choose to show or remove the status bar? (exactly the same options)... and so if iPad must show the Launch screen smaller (without the status bar region), then it must be smaller than the full screen... (no choice to show a full screen image), although that is already quite a big area